# Question about BID vs ASK at the start of Day Trade

Tags: day-trading, bid-ask

So I have been monitoring this IPO recently.
Day trade starts and we are allowed to post bid and asks for 30 minutes before the market officially opens.

I see asks for around 40 for 4500 shares. Lowest ask before market open.
Then I see a bid for 60 for 2000 shares. Highest bid before market open.

Sample Table below:

Bid-------------------------------------Ask

60$ for 2000 shares---------------------40$ for 4500 shares

59$ for 1000 shares---------------------55$ for 1000 shares

58$ for 1500 shares---------------------54$ for 1000 shares

For example the list above is the latest as the market opens.

Will the 40$ for 4500 shares fill in the 60$, 59$ and 58$ bids? Will it be calculated as

60 x 2000 = 120000

59 x 1000 = 59000

58 x 1500 = 87000

120000 + 59000 + 87000 = 266000$

OR......

40 x 4500 = 180000$ ?

Sorry for not so good english.

Comment: Bid prices are lower than ask prices, not higher.

Comment: @BobBaerker he said "before market open".

Answer (score 1):

In most exchanges, there is only **single** opening price during opening auction. The single price should maximize the volume transacted / minimize the imbalance of market orders.

In your case, any single price at or between $40 and $60 can equally maximize the volume of 4500 shares.

How the single price can then be determined is depedent on the exchange.

Take NYSE as an example:

> **Determining Core Open Auction Price**
>
> If there are multiple prices at which the Total Imbalance can equally
> execute, the Indicative Match Price will be based on the price **closest
> to the Auction Reference Price**, including equal to the Auction
> Reference Price itself when that is one of the prices available.
>
> https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-arca/trading-info#core

The definition of Auction Reference Price is:

> **Rule 7.35C. Exchange-Facilitated Auctions**
>
> “Auction Reference Price” means: IPO or Direct Listing Auction:
>
> A price determined under Rule 1.1(s)(1)(F)
>
> https://nyseguide.srorules.com/rules/document?searchId=360953749&treeNodeId=csh-da-filter!WKUS-TAL-DOCS-PHC-%7B4A07B716-0F73-46CC-BAC2-43EB20902159%7D--WKUS_TAL_19401%23teid-44

Which refers to:

> **Rule 1.1. Definitions**
>
> For a security that is a new listing and does not have any
> consolidated last-sale eligible trades on its first trading day, the
> Official Closing Price will be based on a derived **last sale** associated
> with the price of such security before it begins trading on the
> Exchange.
>
> https://nyseguide.srorules.com/rules/document?searchId=360953953&treeNodeId=csh-da-filter!WKUS-TAL-DOCS-PHC-%7B4A07B716-0F73-46CC-BAC2-43EB20902159%7D--WKUS_TAL_19401%23teid-2

Which is likely whichever price is closer to the **IPO Offering Price**.